# How to use RegExp in a URL request correctly?

Tags: regex, query-string

I want to get in the request only users whose name begins with a certain letter. 
But it gives me all the users who have this letter in their name. 
Not just at the beginning! In any place of the name.

```
let firstLetter = 'a';
const responce = await axiosInstance.get(`users?name_like=[/^${firstLetter}/i]`);
```

**/^a/i** 
- Andrew *(true)*
- Djack *(false)*

Comment: Your regular expression is correct. I think this behavior is given by the back-end.

Comment: Thank you, @CristianoSchiaffella, because of you, I continued to look for the problem in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote too many characters. It's much easy.

```
let firstLetter = 'a';
const responce = await axiosInstance.get(`users?name_like=^${firstLetter}`);
```

**Square brackets and slashes are not necessary!**